# Detect Selected dropdown on Add or Remove dropdown Fields Dynamically JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Now i want to upgrade my Add / Remove dropdown fields. here is current code

```js
  var product_row = 0;
    
    function addSpecial() {
        html  = '<tr id="special-pts-row' + product_row + '">';
        html += '  <td ><select name="select_products[' + product_row + '][product_id]" class="getValueSelected" >';
         
        html += '<option value="1">Tshirt - Stock (10)</option>';
        html += '<option value="1">Dress - Stock (14)</option>';
        html += '<option value="2">Jeans - Stock (15)</option>';
         
        html += '  </select></td>';
        html += '  <td ><input id="prioritySpecialId" type="number" name="select_products[' + product_row + '][quantity]" value="" /></td>'; 
        html += '  <td><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#special-pts-row' + product_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_remove }}" class="pts-btn pts-btn-danger">Remove</button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        
        $('#special tbody').append(html);
         
        
        product_row++;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<table id="special">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 80%;">Select Product</td>
      <td>Quantity</td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td class="pts-text-left"><button id="addSpecialButtonId" type="button" onclick="addSpecial();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_special_add }}" class="btn btn-primary">+ Add</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Because each of product have more category like "size" and "colour". so i want to able to get product ID for everytime i selected. but i don't know how to do that.

for debug. i tried to get the selected product ID with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('. getValueSelected').change(function () { 
        var getValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(getValue)
    }); 
}) ;
```

but still can't get the value. how do i able to do that? please help

Comment: I don't see any elements in the snippet with the class `testGetProduct`.

Comment: thank you for the check. i wrong paste the code

Comment: You run your function on page load (document ready), but on page load, the elements of that class have not yet been added to the DOM, so no event handlers are attached.

Comment: You need to get values from all select-box ? Please elaborate

Comment: @Swati i need to get the values everytime i selected the product

Comment: I see your select-box are dynamically created so you need to bind them with static elements i.e :`$('.getValueSelected').change(function () {` to `$('#special').on('change','.getValueSelected',function(){ //your codes})`

Comment: Great!!!! @Swati thank you so much!!.. now i able to upgrade my add/remove function. thankyouu